# Ignoring cases in a string using .include?

Tags: ruby

In this program:

```
thisstring = "sample text"

if thisstring.include? "sample TEXT"
  puts "heres some output"
end
```

Is there a way I could use casecmp here to ignore the caps in TEXT?

Comment: Since the argument of `include?` is, without reference to case, the same as `thisstring`, it would be more apt to see `if thisstring == "sample TEXT"`. btw, though I expect it is an allusion to *South Park*, and cringeworthy, yes, you could have chosen any of at least 10**100 other user names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this?

```
if thisstring.downcase.include?("sample TEXT".downcase)
  puts "heres some output"
end
```

Or:

```
if thisstring.match?(/#{sample TEXT}/i)
  puts "heres some output"
end
```